# What's the meaning of "keep your eyes trained on something"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

Here is the sentence:

> To be able to struggle against capitalism, which permanently revolutionizes all relations, every established Marxism must be periodically transgressed in favour of a theory-practice conception that **keeps its eyes trained on the conditions**.

Comment: Have you checked dictionaries? Look at the 6th definition for "train" in this: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/train

Comment: @Astralbee I'm not surprised the OP doesn't understand. It's definition 4 of the verb, not the noun (scroll down a bit).

Answer (score 2):

Webster's dictionary defines the verb *train* in this context this way:

> to aim something at a target

To *train one's eyes* at something simply means to look at it.

To *keep one's eyes trained* on something means to *keep* focused on it, and not take your eyes off it. It can also be used metaphorically to refer to your mental focus, rather than your literal eyes.